# typeorm, crear entidad de una tabla que ya existe

Tags: typeorm

Quería saber si es posible crear una entidad en typeorm que matchee una tabla que ya existe en mi base de datos, actualmente cuando quiero crear la entidad typeorm me crea una nueva tabla, dejo el código de la entidad.

```
import {
 Column,
 Entity
} from 'typeorm'
@Entity()
export class Diet {

 @Column()
 slug: string

 @Column()
 diet_name: string

 @Column()
 estimated_digestibility: number

 @Column()
 crude_protein_content: number

}
```

Mi tabla actualmente en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Coloca el nombre de la tabla como parámetro de `@Entity`

```
@Entity('nombre_de_tabla')
export class Diet {

 @Column()
 slug: string

 @Column()
 diet_name: string

 @Column()
 estimated_digestibility: number

 @Column()
 crude_protein_content: number

}
```